# XPath to select elements with no children?

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath

```
<div>
<p> text 1 </p> 
<p>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">text 2</a>
</p> 
<p> text 3  </p> 
<p> text 4 </p> 
</div>
```

I used this: `//p` but this also gives me the `<p>` where `text 2` is. I want `<p>`s without children.
I need: `text 1, text 3, text 4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are XPaths for various interpretations of *no children*...

- No ***element*** children:

  ```
  //p[not(*)]
  ```
- No ***text*** children:

  ```
  //p[not(text())]
  ```
- No children ***of any type***:

  ```
  //p[not(node())]
  ```

Replace `p` above with any other element name, or `*` to target elements regardless of name.

Comment: To add a extra alternative, you could also use //p[text()[normalize-space()]], to accomplish the wanted result

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed: Yes, while `//p[not(*)` selects for the *absence* of element children (one interpretation of the requested "no children"), your XPath selects for the *presence* of (non-whitespace-only) text-node children. As such, `//p[not(*)]` would exclude `p` elements with [*mixed content*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66148477/290085) whereas your XPath would also include `p` elements with mixed content.